# How to Pass Hash parameter of Boolean attribute from view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Meta-search Gem to search from table by below controller action. I am Using The Rails version 3.2.9.

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:is_star])
    @feed_entries = @search.page(params[:page])
    @app_keys = AppKey.all
  end
end
```

feed_entries table contain is_star:boolean attribute. So, I just want to pass the hash parameter `is_star == true` into the `params[:is_star]` from view using `form_for` or `link_to` . I tried using the below way.

```
In Views/feed_entries/index.html.erb

<%= link_to "Stared", {:controller => "feed_entries", :action => "index", :is_star => true }%>
```

but the above way is now worked, So I decided to make use of form_for in the below way,

```
<%= form_for(@is_star) do |f|%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :is_star_is_true %>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

But, nothing is worked, please someone help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`true` and `false` when passed as a string is parsed as their truthy value when used in a boolean column.  This is also true for 0, 1, '0' and '1'

```
>> m = Model.new
>> m.active = 'false'
>> m.active? # false
>> m.active = 'true'
>> m.active? # true
```

Knowing this, you can pass 'true' as the value of the `hidden_field`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :is_start, value: 'true' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the value of the parent in the view where the form is being rendere ultimately with something like `<%=params[:is_start] = 1 %>` . I am not sure how the layout of the app is setup. Also make sure to `attr_accessible :is_start`

Update: I may have understood your problem wrong. So try this as well

```
<%= f.hidden_field :is_star, value: 'true' %>
```

Or you could have a radio button ?

```
<%= f.radio_button :is_star, value: 'true' %>
```

Comment: i have edited the question. i missed the value there. But seems like @jvnill already took care of it :)